# I can't find the format file xelatex.fmt

Tags: xetex, linux

I am a newbie to TeX.
I want to use XeLaTeX for my CV, but when I try to compile with Texmaker. a get an error saying:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
```

What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Reinstalling via `sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-xetex` did the job for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try to run `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` which should create all missing format files.

Comment: It still replys with:This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!

Comment: What does the summary output of the above command say?

Answer (score 12):

If you installed TeX from the repositories of your Linux system, you could reinstall the xetex package from a repository.

- Redhat/Fedora: `sudo yum reinstall texlive-xetex`
- Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-xetex`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did a reinstall of texlive-xetex.But I still have the same error.

Comment: I had a version conflict, reinstallation worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you have the proper LaTeX packages installed in addition to the XeLaTeX ones.

In my installation of TeX Live on a Mac, I initially didn't have the `latex` or `latex-bin` packages installed, but I did have `xetex` installed. Running `xelatex` would result in the error message given by cyberscientist.

Try the following to install the LaTeX packages and generate `xelatex.fmt`:

```
tlmgr install latex latex-bin
fmtutil ---all
```

If you need to do things systemwide rather than in your user directory, try

```
sudo tlmgr install latex latex-bin
sudo tlmgr-sys --all
```

For me this unintuitively resulted in generation of `xelatex.fmt`. `xelatex` now runs successfully.

Comment: The last command should be `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

On Fedora 24/25 installing `texinfo-tex` did the trick. On debian this package is called `texinfo`.

```
dnf install texinfo-tex
```

I do not know if it was the package itself fixed the errors or its dependencies.

Installing this package fixed the `xelatex.fmt` error, however it did not fix all the errors in compiling my cv(`xelatex mycv.tex`). Instead I received errors like this:

```
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu1enc.def' not found.
```

Doing a whatprovides for the missing files worked well for me:

```
dnf whatprovides '*/eu1enc.def'
```

Whatprovides you with a package with that filename:

```
texlive-euenc-5:svn19795.0.1h-24.fc24.1.noarch : Unicode font encoding
```

Install that package and cycle compiling your cv, doing `whatprovides` for the missing file, and installing new packages over and over and over.

If you are using an xelatex cv template from latextemplates.com, these are the packages I needed to install:

```
texinfo-tex texlive-euenc texlive-textpos texlive-isodate texlive-titlesec texlive-changepage
```

Comment: Still relevant in Fedora 28 despite https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=717268 ... After installing `texlive-xetex` (texlive-xetex-20170520-42.fc28.x86_64) I installed `texinfo-tex texlive-texconfig texlive-euenc texlive-cm texlive-xetex-def texlive-glyphlist` per that report but it still wasn't enough, so I also installed the packages above and `sudo fmutils-sys --all` finally succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reinstalling TeX Live.

This is how I got **TeX to run** (in Sabayon linux--- based on Gentoo linux), and stop it saying it couldn't find tex.fnt.  Installing Texlive anew worth is a try, since it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Your answer is more of a comment rather than full answer.  Once you’ve gathered 50 reputation points on this site, you’ll be able to [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) and with 15 rep you can [upvote answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: @texenthusiast: I think this answer is valid.  We already have reinstalling recommended in a comment, but it deserves to be an answer.  I've edited the answer to make it a bit clearer (which I couldn't do with a comment).

Comment: @CharlesStewart should we include the command line tweaks mentioned in the comment above inside the answer to bring strength and means. Also its not clear to me [why reinstall did not work ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/i-cant-find-the-format-file-xelatex-fmt/115684?noredirect=1#comment45448_23224). In my opinion. This answer does not add value in addition to [Stefan's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23224/15717) which gives the same with more tweaks

Comment: @Texenthusiast: I had overlooked Stefan's answer - this could be flagged as "duplicate answer".

Comment: @CharlesStewart, texenthusiast: It's OK if multiple users post similar answers. In this case the voting system not flagging should be used to separate good (+1), ok (0) and bad (-1) answers.