# LaTeX/XeLaTeX runs fine with TeXShop but not with bash

Tags: texlive, texshop, unix, bash

I always used TeXShop in the Mac for the last 7 years but now I need to run the compilation remotely. If I run in the terminal (bash shell): XeLaTeX file.tex I get `kpathsea: Running mktexfmt XeLaTeX.fmt I can't find the format file`XeLaTeX.fmt'!` - my guess it is some basic PATH information is missing. I tried man XeLaTeX but I get no manual entry for XeLaTeX. Is there a way I could just extract the settings TeXShop is using?

In this question [I can't find the format file xelatex.fmt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/i-cant-find-the-format-file-xelatex-fmt) the answers are suggestion to re-install texlive but the op there said this did not solve the problem. And here since TeXShop works fine, re-installing does not seem a good idea.

The file exists here: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt

I did sudo hash again as Sean Alfred suggested and this time, it worked. 
Now it compiles fine.

Comment: What does `which xelatex` give you?  If you're giving an absolute path to TeXShop, perhaps this path doesn't match `which` output.  Another idea is `sudo texhash`, but that's just a hunch… I don't really know what it does :)

Comment: I'm not using TeXShop. With TeXShop everything works smooth. which xelatex gives /usr/bin/xelatex. The sudo hash did some updates but TeX, LaTeX, etc... all halt with the can't find the .fmt file

Comment: And `ls -al $(which xelatex)`?  Since TeXShop works, it's probably prudent to try and imitate it.  It's only running shell commands, after all.

Comment: /usr/texbin/xelatex -> xetex

Comment: Same here.  Perhaps you just need to [reinstall TeX](https://tug.org/mactex), but I'd wait a little bit here to see if anyone else has ideas.  Out of curiosity, do you have multiple versions of MacTeX on the computer?  Which is earliest?

Comment: I installed the newest distribution few weeks ago, it kept a 2013 directory. My hunch is related to kpsetool -w -n latex tex which TeXShop uses. I will try it in the command line to see if it helps. It did not...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17131/discussion-between-sergio-parreiras-and-sean-allred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```sh
$ sudo texhash
```

As I understand it, this will search the installation for files and register them with `kpathsea`.