# I can't find the format file `XeLaTeX.fmt'! when compiling with bash script

Tags: xetex, texshop, mactex, bash

Im very new to tex and I am using it to help me with my cover letter.

I installed MacTex and I've been using the TexShop editor.

I have found that I like the XeLaTeX the best so I've been using that.

When I compile using the TexShop editor, I get no errors and it works great.

However, when I compile using bash `XeLaTeX CoverLetter.tex` I get the error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xelatex.fmt
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
```

I know that I have the `xelatex.fmt` downloaded because I can find it at `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt`

I saw some other people who have had this problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201002/latex-xelatex-runs-fine-with-texshop-but-not-with-bash) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/i-cant-find-the-format-file-xelatex-fmt) but the solutions there did not help me unfortunately

Here is what I've tried so far:

- `sudo texhash`
- `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`
- `sudo tlmgr install latex latex-bin`

Some extra info:

- I am on MacOS Catalina
- `which xelatex` gives me `/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex`
- `xelatex` gives me version `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992`

Please let me know if you guys need anymore info, thanks!

Comment: I don't ave a mac and the mac layout may be slightly different to normal texlive ut having your binary in /Library/TeX/ and your other files in /usr/local/texlive seems a bit odd but just as a guess what happens if you use `xelatex CoverLetter.tex` rather than `XeLaTeX CoverLetter.tex` (the latter would not work on a case sensitive system like most linux file systems)

Comment: Should the binary be in the same folder as the other files?

Comment: Also I just ran the script with `xelatex` instead of `XeLaTeX` and I got the same error.

Comment: here is the full error output if it helps:

Comment: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xeLatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xeLatex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /Users/zbeucler/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /Users/zbeucler/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/web2c`

Comment: `mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=xeLatex, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: disabled formats: 5
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 55
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 60
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `xeLatex.fmt'!`

Comment: I figured out the problem, I was in the wrong directory when I was calling `xelatex CoverLetter.tex` and i think xelatex couldnt find the `CoverLetter.tex` file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: a missing document file can't trigger the missing format error but you are using yet another non standard capitalisation for the format name in your comment here `xeLatex.fmt`  I would not expect a xeLatex format to exist, just xelatex.